# Pause/Resume Game

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm having a little trouble finding information on pausing/resuming an application. The only information I can find is for pausing/resuming audio files. I've built an application similar to the 'Simon' game (where you have to repeat a sequence of buttons) but I'm having trouble implementing a pause function. I want to have a button at the top of the screen that says 'Pause' and hitting it will pause the game and change the text of the button to say 'Resume' basically, I want everything to freeze except for the Resume button.

I've set up what I think would be an okay set up for determining the state of the button, but I have no idea what to put inside; the only sort of waiting functions I've dealt with thus far are ones that sleep for a predetermined length of time (NSTimer, etc.)

If anyone could help I would be greatly appreciative!

```
- (IBAction)paused:(id)sender
{
  UIButton *pause = (UIbutton *)sender;
  NSString *state = pause.titleLabel.text; 
  if ([state isEqualToString:@"Pause"])
  {
   //If the text is set to 'pause' that means the game is running 
   //pressing this button will pause the game
  }else
  {
   //If the text is set to resume that means the game is paused
   //pressing this button will resume the game
  }
}
```

Comment: What does pause mean for your game? What stops working when paused? What 'freezes'? Are those things moving, or they should just stop responding to touches?

Comment: There are a series of animations the play (buttons light up in a sequence, when they light up they use the highlighted property) when the sequence is done playing the user gets to put in their sequence but touching the buttons. Ideally, I would like the pause to stop the sequence playback if its happening and stop user interaction if its not. I could also compromise by only disabling user interaction when the game is paused (i feel like this option may be better overall because pausing the game mid sequence might make the user forget what was played before the pause happened.)

Comment: You should most likely cancel the current sequence and restart it. You can diasble the buttons in a loop.